# Error from linear regression in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I am trying to implement simple linear regression on iris dataset.
my code is:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
x = df['sepal_length']
y = df['sepal_width']
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x,y)
```

However, I got this error:

> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a programming question than a data science question and would therefore be better suited for the stackoverflow stackexchange. The error already gives quite a good explanation on what the issue is, you are passing a 1D array to the linear regression where it is expecting a 2D array. This because you are using a single string to index the feature column, which returns a `pandas.Series`, instead of using a list of strings, which would return a `pandas.DataFrame`. Changing the way you are selecting your feature(s) from the dataframe solves the issue:

```py
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
x = df[['sepal_length']] # change from single string to list of strings
y = df['sepal_width']
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: thank you so much for clarification.